# What is the xcalib -screen number for the HDMI monitor?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, monitors, xrandr

I must use a VGA-to-DVI cable and a HDMI cable to run two monitors.  I'm trying to invert the colors on both monitors but I can only invert one of them:

```
$ xcalib -invert -alter -s 0 #works


$ xcalib -invert -alter -s 1
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  129 (XFree86-VidModeExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (XF86VidModeGetGammaRampSize)
  Value in failed request:  0x17
  Serial number of failed request:  10
  Current serial number in output stream:  10
```

I unplugged the HDMI cable and plugged it back in again.  Now, the `xcalib  -invert -alter -s 0` command inverts the other monitor.  In other words, both monitors are inverted for the moment but I had to re-connect one monitor to get that to happen.

Here is my setup:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

Graphics card:

```
$ lspci |egrep -i vga
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 [Radeon HD 4200]
```

This is Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS w/gnome-panel.  The problem still occurs on Ubuntu 14.04 but the work-around does not work.

Comment: What graphics card do you have? What driver (free or proprietary) to you run?

Comment: `egrep -i "video driver" /var/log/Xorg.0.log` shows me `X.Org Video Driver: 11.0`

Comment: interestingly, in [my setup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230870/xcalib-i-a-controls-only-one-of-two-screens-can-it-control-both/448585?noredirect=1#448585), `xrandr` says 'Can't open display', most strange!

Comment: I have a work-around... It got more complicated with Ubuntu 14.04 (with an extra step to -s HDMI...). Basically, I invert once (one screen) using -s 0 the I unplug and re-plug my HDMI cable. Then I invert again (same screen same command).. Finally I invert -s HDMI-0.. and both monitors are inverted. I can then toggle one of them with the -s 0. So, aside from this being so ridiculous this holds me over.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use xcalib to invert your monitor. You will have to use the following utility to overcome this limitation.

> Note that as of date of last testing (2014, xcalib version 0.8) xcalib
>   has not been able to invert the colors on all monitors in a
>   multi-monitor setup, because all monitors are presented by the X11
>   server as a single screen. Thus this limitation is coming from the X11
>   server. xrandr-invert-colors does not have this limitation, because it
>   uses XRandR API, which correctly handles all attached monitors.

Reference: https://github.com/zoltanp/xrandr-invert-colors

Answer (score 1):

From trial and error `xcalib`'s `-screen` parameter takes the zero indexed number of your monitor according to your `xrandr` output, ie, in your case `xcalib -s 0` (the default) will control `VGA-0` and `xcalib -s 1` will control `HDMI-0`.